# Where is the PIN number to be found in Windows 10 Developer's Settings?

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

[image]

I am trying to test a Windows 10 Universal program on a remote machine, in Visual Studio 2017. I have this working on one of two remote machines. On the second remote PC, however, I get the message, shown above, upon an attempt to deploy the application in Visual Studio 2017.

I cannot find a PIN number in "the device’s developer settings" on the remote machine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check that in Visual Studio in Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging, Authentication Type is set to None.